# Django-nose failure - KeyError: u'en-us'

Tags: python, django, django-nose

I have all of my `TestCase` files in a django app called 'tests'. Running a specific `TestCase` works just fine with this command:

`python run manage.py test tests.myTestCaseFile`

However, when i run the entire set of TestCases in the tests folder this fails:

`python run manage.py test tests`

In this case many ImportErrors are triggered as well as KeyError: 'en-us'. Essentially every single `TestMethod` errors out in one way or another.

Any ideas what could be happening here?

**NOTE:** I have already tried to import myapp.urls in the shell and reverse(urlname) works just fine there..

Comment: Do you see the same effect if you compare `python manage.py test tests.myTestCaseFile` to `python manage.py test tests` ?  Is coverage an essential factor in the problem?

Comment: No it's not - thanks for pointing this out. Seems the root cause is something within the django-nose loader. Still troubleshooting on that end. I removed references to coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this issue:

- **KeyError: u'en-us'** seems to occur anytime there is an import error in **any test module**

I had a test file which was testing functionality that did not exist in the current branch.

Seems that **an import error in any test file** prevents execution of the **entire test suite.**